# Pandas to csv function issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a dataframe using dictionary data structure and convert it csv file in my local downloads folder but the file is not downloading nor it has appeared in my local path.
please find the code below.

```
   import pandas as pd
   dict1= {'1':['akash'],'2':['sanjana']}
   df= pd.DataFrame(dict1)
   print(df)
   df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\FCI-1863\\Downloads\\pandas.csv",index=False)
```

Tried even raw string and even path library but nothing seems to work.

```
   df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\FCI-1863\Downloads\pandas.csv',index=False)
```

I tried using path library

```
   from pathlib import Path
   filepath=Path(r'C:\Users\FCI-1863\Downloads\pandas.csv')

   import pandas as pd
   dict1= {'1':['akash'],'2':['sanjana']}
   df= pd.DataFrame(dict1)
   df.to_csv(filepath)
```

[image]
In the above image we can see that the file is created without throwng any exception.

[image]
However I am able to see a cross mark on some of the folders saying storage space is full.

**But I had mentioned downloads path which does not have a cross symbol.**

I am still confused whether it is an storage error.

**Here I am able to see the csv files in google colab inmemory content folder.

guess I have to download it from here.**
[image]

Comment: Did you try simply a name without 'pandas.csv' ?

Comment: Your code works on my machine and my python version, if the indent is corrected after copy&past.

Comment: Given the indentation and lack of any error, your code snippet may be pulled out of a larger code context that may have conditional logic where this block may never run. Please provide fuller code for [mre].

Comment: Hi @Parfait I have provided you the minimal reproducible code itself.
Let's have a g-meet tom when your free.
Please email me : arjun.kavitharani@gmail.com
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi @Hermann12  can you please have a look at my question above.
I have made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is correct and that there are no problems with the way you are sending the data to a CSV file or generating the DataFrame. However, there might be a few reasons for this issue:

- Permissions (you have Permissions in that Folder)
- File Overwriting
- Error Handling
- Incorrect Path
- Anti-virus/Firewall
- Disk Space

You can use a try-except block to see what's the issue here:

```
try:
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\FCI-1863\Downloads\pandas.csv', index=False)
    print("CSV file created successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```

Comment: Thanks @MD Kawsar Let me check and ping you back

Comment: OP's code would have raised an error without `try...except` handling and OP would have posted such an error. My guess is posted code is cut out from a larger code base and this block for various reasons does not run at all. We need more code lines to help OP.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, The above code is not OP's code. This is the raw code which  I am testing in my google colab for DA work.

Comment: Hi  @Parfait I have updated the above question.
Maybe you can have a look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Parfait I am not sure about this behaviour of google colab. do you know  the reason why colab is behaving this way. any guess?